# QField: Styles do not match the QGIS-project

Tags: style, qfield

I have created a forestry related QGIS-project (in Version 3.10) with a polygon-layer, that displays the different tree-stands with different colors. The project looks fine in the desktop application.

After I copy the project to my Tablet and start Qfield (Version 1.7.6), some of the polygons end up without a color, even though the key-number for the style is clearly valid.

I have created similar maps in the past  with the same style, and never had any problems with the results.

What could be the problem?

Comment: you need to provide more information (at last the exact symbology setting for your polygon, at best some picture of how it look in QGIS and QField and some exemple data of polygons that work and dont work) in it's current state there are no way of telling what's could be wrong

Comment: Thank you J.R., I apologize for the lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a hunch that maybe the App is the problem...
Since I saved an apk-Version of the previous QField-release, 1.0.3 "Matterhorn" I was able to delete the current version of QField and replace it with the old version "Matterhorn".
Tada, that solved the problem!